# How to move magic tile by tile on a game?

Tags: java, 2d

I have a 2D tile game and my hero can use magic(in this case fire), and the goal is to make the fireball move tile by tile until it finds either a wall or an enemy and to make the game stop while the fire is moving. I already have the fire moving and stopping if there is a wall or an enemy(and damaging the enemy). The problem is i can't seem to make the game show the fireball change from tile to tile, which means when i launch the fireball the game automatically shows me the fireball in its last position before collision, and then it disappears from the tiles. Anyone got any ideas as to what I am doing wrong or what i should do to make the game update the fire tile by tile? (Btw i thought it might have something to do with my observer but I've tried thread.sleep and wait() and it isn't quite working, maybe I am doing it the wrong way).Thank you for your help and if you guys need any code just ask.

```
public class ImageMatrixGUI extends Observable {

private static final ImageMatrixGUI INSTANCE = new ImageMatrixGUI();

private final String IMAGE_DIR = "images";
private final int SQUARE_SIZE;
private final int N_SQUARES_WIDTH;
private final int N_SQUARES_HEIGHT;

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JPanel info;

private Map<String, ImageIcon> imageDB = new HashMap<String, ImageIcon>();

private List<ImageTile> images = new ArrayList<ImageTile>();
private List<ImageTile> statusImages = new ArrayList<ImageTile>();

private int lastKeyPressed;
private boolean keyPressed;

private ImageMatrixGUI() {
    SQUARE_SIZE = 48;
    N_SQUARES_WIDTH = 10;
    N_SQUARES_HEIGHT = 10;
    init();
}
public static ImageMatrixGUI getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
 public void setName(final String name) {
    frame.setTitle(name); 
}

    private void init() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new RogueWindow();
    info = new InfoWindow();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(N_SQUARES_WIDTH * SQUARE_SIZE, N_SQUARES_HEIGHT * SQUARE_SIZE));
    info.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(N_SQUARES_WIDTH * SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE));
    info.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(info, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    initImages();

    new KeyWatcher().start();

    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            lastKeyPressed = e.getKeyCode();
            keyPressed = true;
            releaseObserver();
        }
    });
}

synchronized void releaseObserver() {
    notify();
}

synchronized void waitForKey() throws InterruptedException {
    while (!keyPressed) {
        wait();
    }
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(lastKeyPressed);
    keyPressed = false;
}

private void initImages() {
    File dir = new File(IMAGE_DIR);
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        assert (f.getName().lastIndexOf('.') != -1);
        imageDB.put(f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().lastIndexOf('.')),
                new ImageIcon(IMAGE_DIR + "/" + f.getName()));
    }
}
public void go() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void newImages(final List<ImageTile> newImages) {
    synchronized (images) { // Added 16-Mar-2016
        if (newImages == null)
            return;
        if (newImages.size() == 0)
            return;
        for (ImageTile i : newImages) {
            if (!imageDB.containsKey(i.getName())) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such image in DB " + i.getName());
            }
        }
        images.addAll(newImages);
    }
}
 public void removeImage(final ImageTile image) {
    synchronized (images) { 
        images.remove(image);
    }
}
    public void addImage(final ImageTile image) {
    synchronized (images) { 
        images.add(image);
    }
}
    public void clearImages() {
    synchronized (images) {
        images.clear();
    }

    public void newStatusImages(final List<ImageTile> newImages) {
    synchronized (statusImages) { 
        if (newImages == null)
            return;
        if (newImages.size() == 0)
            return;
        for (ImageTile i : newImages) {
            if (!imageDB.containsKey(i.getName())) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such image in DB " + i.getName());
            }
        }
        statusImages.addAll(newImages);
    }
}

  public void removeStatusImage(final ImageTile image) {
    synchronized (statusImages) {
        statusImages.remove(image);
    }

 public void addStatusImage(final ImageTile image) {
    synchronized (statusImages) { 
        statusImages.add(image);
    }
}
    public void clearStatus() {
    synchronized (statusImages) { 
        statusImages.clear();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
private class RogueWindow extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + "
        // repainting");
        synchronized (images) { 
            for (ImageTile i : images) {

                g.drawImage(imageDB.get(i.getName()).getImage(), i.getPosition().getX() * SQUARE_SIZE,
                        i.getPosition().getY() * SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, frame);
            }
        }
    }
}

 @SuppressWarnings("serial") 
  private class InfoWindow extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        synchronized (statusImages) { 
            for (ImageTile i : statusImages)
                g.drawImage(imageDB.get(i.getName()).getImage(), i.getPosition().getX() * SQUARE_SIZE, 0,
                        SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, frame);

        }
    }
}

   private class KeyWatcher extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true)
                waitForKey();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
    public void update() {
    frame.repaint();
}

    public void dispose() {
    images.clear();
    statusImages.clear();
    imageDB.clear();
    frame.dispose();
}
    public Dimension getGridDimension() {
    return new Dimension(N_SQUARES_WIDTH, N_SQUARES_HEIGHT);
}
```

---

```
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    Integer keycode = (Integer) arg1;

    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP || keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT
            || keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
    moveTheHero(keycode);
    }
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_1 || keycode == KeyEvent.VK_2 || keycode == KeyEvent.VK_3){
        System.out.println("Key pressed " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keycode));
        dropItem(keycode);
    }
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        System.out.println("Key pressed " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keycode));
        launchMagic();
    }
}





public void launchMagic(){
    if(hero.getMagic()!=0){
        hero.removeStatus(hero.getMagic()-1);
        hero.loseMagic();
        Fire fire = new Fire(hero.getPosition());
        fire.changeInGame();
        Direction direction = fire.closestEnemyDirection(currentRoom);
        currentRoom.getTiles().add(fire);
        while(fire.getInGame()){
            fire.move(currentRoom, direction);
        }
        currentRoom.removeTiles(fire.getName(), fire.getPosition());
        manageEnemies();
        gui.newStatusImages(hero.getStatus());
        gui.newImages(currentRoom.getTiles());
    }else System.out.println("You don't have any magic");
}
```

Comment: ok guy you thought you would escape? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378939/magic-movement-in-game-tile-by-tile

Comment: I'm actually working with the other guy in the same project, and since no one was responding to him i though i would give it a try also because we're running out of time and this would really help us.

Comment: Tip: Look into using a timer and waiting a set amount of seconds between each tile render. If you want more help then break your code down into a small tidy example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve